# Обработка типизированного файла

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! Есть функция

```
void udalenie()
{
    system("cls");
    i = 0;
    fstream fp;
    p = new lomb[100];
    char name[60];
    rus("введите название товара:n");
    cin >> name;
    fp.open(fn, ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!fp.is_open()) {
        rus("нет файлаn");
        getch();
        system("pause");
    }
    fp.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (fp.read((char *) &p[i], sizeof(lomb))) {
        if (fp.eof())
            break;
        if (strcmp(p[i].tovar, name) == 0) {
            p[i].udal = 0;
            fp.seekp(-sizeof(lomb), ios::cur);
            fp.write((char *) &p[i], sizeof(lomb));
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    fp.close();
    delete[]p;
    cout << "запись удалена!n";
    system("pause");
}
```

При завершении размер обрабатываемого файла становится 4Гб, причем во время выполнения все переменные и файловые указатели содержат правильные значения. Файл закрывается минуты две. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: зачем закрывать вопрос? я же удалил старый

Comment: fp.seekp(-sizeof(lomb), ios::cur);
вы уверенны, что дам должен быть МИНУС??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В программе не смещается указатель вывода в поток. При вызове `fp.seekp(-sizeof(lomb), ios::cur)` указатель в начале файла. Попробуйте `fp.seekp(fp.tellg()-sizeof(lomb))`

Comment: Точно. 

@woland, обратите внимание, что в fstream **два** независимых указателя позиции в файле, один get pointer (seekg), а другой put pointer (seekp).

См., например, [здесь](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/)